# How to configure eslint to catch duplicate import on same line?

Tags: javascript, eslint, es6-modules

Consider the following Javascript import:

```js
import { merge } from 'module';
import { find } from 'module';
```

`eslint` will give warning/error on rule [no-duplicate-imports](https://eslint.org/docs/2.13.1/rules/no-duplicate-imports)

but, how can I configure `eslint` to warns/error if I write code like:

```js
import { merge, find, merge } from 'module'; // should have error because of double "merge" import
```

Comment: So, as far as you know, `eslint` does not support this?

Comment: In your configuration file, trying setting `"parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": "latest",
    "sourceType": "module"
  }` (ecmaVersion >= 6 should work).  Using `eslint` 8.10.0 this throws following error on my end: `Parsing error: Identifier 'merge' has already been declared`.